# DAO recordset settings for reading

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I have a database from which I create many Excel files via DAO recordset+CopyFromRecordset. There is an odd error where the CopyFromRecordset command sometimes produces an error, but if I just simply press Continue in the debugger it goes on without problem. This reminded me I needed to set up the parameters for OpenRecordset - but how?

What I do is query different parts of a table and put the queried part to an Excel file. Read only recordset.

So, `RecordsetTypeEnum` is `dbOpenSnapshot`, that is clear.

`RecordsetOptionEnum`? I use dbFailOnError when I want to read/write, but makes no sense in this case. Does dbRunAsync make sense, since I'm querying the same table multiple times in relatively quick succession? Any other parameter that is useful?

`LockTypeEnum`? Is there a difference when using a snapshot?

I couldn't find any good comprehensive description of these settings.

My code below, not that is too relevant:

```
  Set MyDb = CurrentDb

  Set rsGLAP = MyDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT GL_Account FROM APCommentedData WHERE CoCode = """ & CoCd & """;", dbOpenSnapshot)
  If Not (rsGLAP.BOF And rsGLAP.EOF) Then

    rsGLAP.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsGLAP.EOF

      Set wsAccount = wb.worksheets.Add
      wsAccount.Name = rsGLAP.Fields(0).Value

      Set rs1 = MyDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM APCommentedData WHERE CoCode = """ & CoCd & """ AND GL_Account = """ & rsGLAP.Fields(0).Value & """;",dbOpenSnapshot)

      'headers
      For i = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
        wsAccount.cells(33, i + 1).Value = rs1.Fields(i).Name
      Next

      'data
        wsAccount.cells(34, 1).copyfromrecordset rs1

      rs1.Close
      Set rs1 = Nothing
      rsGLAP.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Comment: Are you still getting error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Haven't ran it since I added the snapshot option. But that error is really not the point of my question, I can handle that. I'd like to know which settings are useful for my scenario, and in general which ones improve performance.

Comment: Yes, same error happens with dbOpenSnapshot.